# Different Boundary Style on each edge of 3D Plot

Tags: plotting

I am wondering is there a possibility to define different properties on each edge of `Plot3D` (different colours or thicknesses) by using `BoundaryStyle`?

Comment: BoundaryStyle refers to the boundary of the plotted function, and such a boundary can have multiple segments, unconnected.  Can you point to a figure online that shows what you seek?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Update 2:** We can avoid manual adjustments in the mesh specifications for mesh lines on the boundary using the option  `Method -> {"BoundaryOffset" -> False}` (see [this answer by MichaelE2](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/173431/125)):

```
 Plot3D[Sin[x + y^2], {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3},
  BoundaryStyle -> None, 
  PlotStyle -> Opacity[.7], 
  MeshFunctions -> {# &, #2 &}, 
  Mesh -> {{{-3, Directive[Thick, Red]}, {3, Directive[Thick, Cyan]}}, 
      {{-3, Directive[Thick, Purple]}, {3, Directive[Thick, Blue]}}}, 
  Method -> {"BoundaryOffset" -> False}]
```

[image]

**Update:** an alternative approach using `ParametricPlot3D`:

```
ClearAll[boundaryPlot3D]
boundaryPlot3D[func : _[__], a : {x_, x1_, x2_}, b : {y_, y1_, y2_}, 
   pltstyle_: {Red, Orange, Blue, Purple}][o : OptionsPattern[]] := 
 Module[{fs = (({x, y, func} /. #) & /@ ((Thread[# -> {##2}] & @@ #)) /. 
        y | x -> u ) & /@ {a, b}, styles = Partition[pltstyle, 2]}, 
  Show[ParametricPlot3D[{x, y, func}, a, b, o, Mesh -> None, 
    PlotStyle -> Opacity[.5]], 
   ParametricPlot3D[Evaluate@fs[[1]], {u, y1, y2}, 
    PlotStyle -> styles[[1]], o, BaseStyle -> Thick],
   ParametricPlot3D[Evaluate@fs[[2]], {u, x1, x2}, 
    PlotStyle -> styles[[2]], o, BaseStyle -> Thick], 
   PlotRange -> All]]
```

***Examples:***

```
boundaryPlot3D[Sin[x + y^2], {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}][]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
boundaryPlot3D[Sin[x + y^2], {x, -6, 6}, {y, -3, 3}][]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
boundaryPlot3D[
  Sin[x y + y^2], {x, -3, 3}, {y, -6, 6}, {Directive[Thick, Red], 
   Directive[Thick, Dashed, Green], Directive[Thick, Dashed, Orange], Purple}][]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
boundaryPlot3D[Sin[x + x y + y^2], {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}][] /. 
 Line -> (Tube[#, .1] &)
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

**Original answer:**

I don't think it can be done using `BoundaryStyle`, but you can use `MeshFunctions` and `Mesh` to get the desired result:

```
Plot3D[Sin[x + y^2], {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}, BoundaryStyle -> None, 
 PlotStyle -> Opacity[.7],  MeshFunctions -> {# &, #2 &}, 
 Mesh -> {{{-3 + .001, Directive[Thick, Red]}, 
           {3 - .001,  Directive[Thick, Orange]}}, 
          {{-3 + .001, Directive[Thick, Purple]}, 
           {3 - .001, Directive[Thick, Blue]}}}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
Plot3D[Sin[x + y^2], {x, -6, 6}, {y, -3, 3}, BoundaryStyle -> None, 
 PlotStyle -> Opacity[.5], MeshFunctions -> {# &, #2 &}, 
 Mesh -> {{{-6 + .001, Directive[Thick, Red]}, 
           {6 - .001,  Directive[Thick, Orange]}},
          {{-3 + .001, Directive[Thick, Purple]}, 
           {3 - .001, Directive[Thick, Blue]}}}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: After examining the `FullForm` of the first example from the [docs](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/BoundaryStyle.html), I found there this piece: `{{Directive[RGBColor[1, 0, 0], Thickness[Large]], 
  Line[{950, 1, ....}]}}`. I guess the numbers in `Line` could be associated with each edge, and split into different colorings (maybe with `Cases`...?), but that looks so tedious that `Mesh*` seems to be the best option.

Comment: @corey979, post-processing was my first thought, but, unfortunately, for the boundary we get a single `Line` and i felt too lazy totry to find a way to break it into 4 pieces.

Comment: @corey979 you might be right. There is no point to dig into it. Solution with `Mesh` also solves my problem. Thx