# What are the possible Method option values for plotting functions?

Tags: plotting, options, undocumented

Many plotting functions have a `Method` options with descriptions like this:

- `Plot`: "the method to use for refining curves"
- `RegionPlot`: "the method to use for refining regions"
- `ContourPlot`: "the method to use for refining contours"

The purpose of this option is documented (control mesh refinement), but its possible values are not.

What values can we use for this option in plotting functions, especially as relating to mesh refinement?

---

I found a number of related questions, but there the answers only provide starting points. There is no discussion of how to control mesh/curve refinement.

- [Method options for DensityPlot and ContourPlot](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/69448/12)
- [What Method values are available for Plot?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/92513/12)

Comment: I'm sure you're aware of `MaxBend`/`Refinement -> {ControlValue -> (* radian angle *) }` for `Plot[]` and `ParametricPlot[]`, at least. (I don't know if there are other functions that accept these settings.)

Comment: @J.M. Right!  I actually forgot about those. In this case my starting point was RegionPlot, then later I noticed that the description of the Method option is almost identical for all plotting fuctions.

Comment: For `ListPlot` the starting point is [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/87818/280) answer by  Mr.Wizard and [comment](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/87808/new-behavior-of-plotrange-in-mathematica-10/87818#comment239068_87818) under it.

Answer (score 12):

I found one:

For `ParametricPlot3D` (and `Plot`, `Plot3D`),

```
Method -> {"BoundaryOffset" -> False}
```

causes the sampling to include the end points of the interval(s), for both surfaces and curves.  By default, end points are not included.

Contrariwise, for `ParametricPlot`,

```
Method -> {"BoundaryOffset" -> True}
```

cause the sampling to be inset slightly from the end points of the interval(s), for both curves and regions.  By default, the end point are included.

I discovered this looking for an answer to [Unexpected Holes in Contourplot3D](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/173397/unexpected-holes-in-contourplot3d/173428#173428).