# Methods for ListPlot3D

Tags: plotting

In the documentation for [ListPlot3D](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ListPlot3D.html) we see that there is the option `Method`, but which methods are avalaible? I cannot find a documentation page for it.

If that is relevant I use version 10.0

Comment: The suboptions in[`Graphics3D >> Options >> Method`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Graphics3D.html) seems to work. There may be others.

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov That question is very similar to mine, but does not really answer my question as there are no actual methods listed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a closely related [thread of question and discussions](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/156475/what-are-the-possible-method-option-values-for-plotting-functions) out there. While it doesn't give a definitive and complete answer, it does shed some light on the topic.

I tried to get Methods for `ListPlot3D` using one of the old functions from this thread:

```
getList2[name_String] := 
  Module[{options, idx, z1, z2}, options = Names[name <> "`*"];
   options = ToExpression /@ options;
   options = Flatten[Last@Reap@Do[z1 = Options[options[[i]]];
        If[z1 != {}, z2 = Cases[z1, Rule["Method", x_] :> Method -> x];
         If[Length[z2] != 0, Sow[{options[[i]], z2}]]], {i, 
         Length[options]}], 1];
   (*rest for formatting*)idx = Range[Length[options]];
   options = {#[[1]], TableForm[#[[2]]]} & /@ options;
   options = Insert[options[[#]], #, 1] & /@ idx;
   options = 
    Insert[options, {"#", "Option", "Options to this option"}, 1]];
```

but got an empty list in return. Although, for `NDSolve` it does work as expected.

Does anybody know what's up here?

Comment: Aw man it says I voted this down but I honestly didn’t and don’t remember even seeing this thread? So, I’m sorry! I can not undo it, SE won’t let me. I think that’s kinda lame, to be quite honest. (If you edit the answer I can undo it!) please, clarify what the output you get is when you evaluate the expression you made here?

Comment: @CATrevillian the question was recently edited, so you should be able to revert your downvote, if you’d like.