# RegionPlot edges with different BoundaryStyles?

Tags: plotting, inequalities

I executed this command:

RegionPlot[x > 2 && x < 3 && y > 2 && y < 3, {x, 0, 4}, {y, 0, 4}]

[image]

I would like the top and right sides of the square to be dashed lines and the bottom and left sides of the square to be thick, solid lines.  How do I do this?

Comment: Do you want to plot this specific rectangle with that requirement? Or can the region represent something else (a ball, for example)?

Comment: This specific rectangle

Comment: @mont2223 Then generate it from `Graphics` primitives, using appropriately styled `Rectangle` and `Line` objects. MUCH easier!

Answer (score 5):

One possible way is to use the options `MeshFunctions` and `Mesh`:

```
RegionPlot[x >= 2 && x <= 3 && y >= 2 && y <= 3, {x, 0, 4}, {y, 0, 4}, 
 PlotPoints -> 100, 
 BoundaryStyle -> None, 
 PlotStyle -> Opacity[.3, Yellow],
 MeshFunctions -> {# &, #2 &}, 
 Mesh -> {{{2, Opacity[1, Red]}, {3, Opacity[1, Cyan]}}, 
  {{2, Opacity[1, Purple]}, {3, Opacity[1, Blue]}}},
 BaseStyle -> Thick]
```

[image]

An alternative way is to use `Graphics` (as suggested by MarcoB in comments):

```
Graphics[{FaceForm[Opacity[.3, Yellow]], Rectangle[{2, 2}, {3, 3}], 
  Thick, MapThread[List, {{Red, Cyan, Purple, Blue}, Line /@ 
   {{{2, 2}, {2, 3}}, {{3, 2}, {3, 3}}, {{2, 2}, {3, 2}}, {{2, 3}, {3, 3}}}}]},
 PlotRange -> {{0, 4}, {0, 4}}, Frame -> True]
```

[image]

A more convenient way to avoid listing of line coordinates:

```
{lines, polygon} = MeshPrimitives[
     BoundaryDiscretizeRegion[Rectangle[{2, 2}, {3, 3}], 
      MaxCellMeasure -> Infinity], #] & /@ {1, 2};

Graphics[{FaceForm[Opacity[.3, Yellow]], polygon,
  Thick, MapThread[List, {{Purple, Cyan, Blue, Red}, lines}]},
 PlotRange -> {{0, 4}, {0, 4}}, Frame -> True]
```

> same picture

```
SeedRandom[1];
randompolygon = RandomPolygon[10];

Graphics[{FaceForm[Opacity[.25, Yellow]], randompolygon, 
  Thick, {RandomColor[], Line @ #} & /@ 
   Partition[Append[#, First @ #] & @ randompolygon[[1]], 2, 1]}]
```

[image]

**Related Q/A:** [Different Boundary Style on each edge of 3D Plot](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/140940/125)