# RegionPlot for " < " and " <= " is the same on the boundary?

Tags: plotting, regions

```
RegionPlot[{1 <= x < 5 && 2 < y < 5}, {x, 0.8, 5.2}, {y, 1.8, 5.2}, BoundaryStyle -> Dashed]
```

Is there a way to use SOLID line for "less or equal to" and use DASHED line for just "less than"?

Thought Mathematica would be using this kind of style by default as it is more common in the Maths World??

Comment: Does this help you? https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/238720/regionplot-edges-with-different-boundarystyles/238722#238722

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Define two [`ImplicitRegion`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ImplicitRegion.html)s and `RegionPlot` them with different `BoundaryStyle`s:

```
impreg = ImplicitRegion[{1 <= x < 5 && 2 < y < 5}, {{x, 0.8, 5.2}, {y, 1.8, 5.2}}];

impreg2 = 
  ImplicitRegion[{1 == x && 2 < y < 5}, {{x, 0.8, 5.2}, {y, 1.8, 5.2}}];

RegionPlot[{impreg, impreg2}, 
 BoundaryStyle -> {1 -> Dashed, 2 -> Directive[Thick, Dashing[{}], ColorData[97]@1]}]
```

[image]

A more complicated example:

```
ir1 = ImplicitRegion[-1 <= x^2 + y^3 < 2 && x + y <= 1, {{x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}}];

ir2 = ImplicitRegion[-1 == x^2 + y^3 < 2 && x + y <= 1, {{x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}}];

ir3 = ImplicitRegion[-1 <= x^2 + y^3 < 2 && x + y == 1, {{x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}}];

RegionPlot[{ir1, ir2, ir3}, 
 BoundaryStyle -> {1 -> Dashed, 
   2 -> Directive[Thick, Dashing[{}], ColorData[97]@1], 
   3 -> Directive[Thick, Dashing[{}], ColorData[97]@1]}]
```

[image]

Comment: Just seemed a bit "more complicated" than it should be, as this kind of notation is so commonly used in plotting such regions....THANKS.