# Illustrate an unbounded region with RegionPlot

Tags: plotting

When plotting

```
RegionPlot[y>=x^2,{x,-2,2},{y,0,4}]
```

I would like to have the top boundary to be Dashed, to illustrate the fact that the region is unbounded.

I did not find a satisfactory way to do that yet.

Comment: Similar to [238722](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/238720/regionplot-edges-with-different-boundarystyles/238722#238722).

Comment: I saw that one, and it does not work properly in all cases.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What about

```
Show[RegionPlot[y >= x^2, {x, -2, 2}, {y, 0, 4}], 
Plot[4, {x, -2, 2}, PlotStyle -> {Lighter[Blue], Dashed}]]
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

You can also add the option `Method -> {"BoundaryOffset" -> False}` in `RegionPlot` and use the option [`Mesh`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Mesh.html) as follows:

```
RegionPlot[y >= x^2, {x, -2, 3/2}, {y, 0, 4},
 BoundaryStyle -> None,
 Method -> {"BoundaryOffset" -> False},
 Mesh -> {
   {{3/2, Directive[Opacity[1], Thick, DotDashed, Blue]}}, 
   {{4, Directive[Opacity[1], Thick, Dashed, Red]}}}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Using the example by @kglr.

```
Clear[reg, rectangle, member, boundary];
reg = ImplicitRegion[y >= x^2, {x, y}];
rectangle = Rectangle[{-2, 0}, {3/2, 4}];
member = RegionMember[reg];
boundary = 
  Region[Style[
    RegionIntersection[DiscretizeRegion@reg, 
     RegionBoundary@rectangle], AbsoluteDashing[{1, 10}, 0, "Round"], 
    AbsoluteThickness[4], Darker@Cyan]];
Show[RegionPlot[member@{x, y}, {x, y} ∈ rectangle, 
  BoundaryStyle -> None], boundary]
```

[image]

Comment: `Region[Style[
  RegionIntersection[DiscretizeRegion@reg, RegionBoundary@rectangle], 
  AbsoluteDashing[{1, 12}, -6, CapForm["Round"]], 
  AbsoluteThickness[6], Darker@Cyan]]`